# AVAudioPlayer isPlaying always return null

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, avaudioplayer

I'm experiencing an odd problem with AVAudioPlayer class.
Everytime I try to access one of it's properties they are null.

```
// Get the file path to the song to play.
 NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pSound.fileName 
               ofType:pSound.fileType] retain];

 // Convert the file path to a URL.
 NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

 NSError* err;
 //Initialize the AVAudioPlayer
 self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&err];

    if( err ){
  NSLog(@"Initializing failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
 }
 else{
  [self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
  [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
  self.playCount = self.playCount + 1;
        NSLog(@"%@", [self.audioPlayer isPlaying]); //this displays null; also if I call it at a later time
 };

 [filePath release];
 [fileURL release];
```

Any Ideas?

EDIT: Oddly enough when I save isPlaying to a bool and print the bool I get a value...

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this problem? I have the same problem and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.audioPlayer isPlaying]);
```

%@ - mean that you want to print result of [yourObject toString]
so if you want to check bool value returned by [self.audioPlayer isPlaying] - you should use %d.

p.s. don't foget call [audioPlayer play]; 
;)

Comment: Oh ok thank you.
But anyway if I access the value in a if it's always returning null too. I have a playOrPause method where I check that.

Since it's working when I first assign the value to a variable and then query the variable it doesn't matter I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the (audioPlay.playing) instead of [audioPlayer isPlaying]

```
if (audioPlayer.playing) {
        [audioPlayer stop];
} else {
        [audioPlayer play];
}
```