# How do I set an AVAudioRecorder local instance as Property so it stays retained?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, avaudioplayer

I've created a class of object called ARecorder. (ARecorder.h / ARecorder.m)  Implementation has a few methods:

```
-void(setupAndRecord) 
-(void)stop
```

etc.

I setup an `AVAudioSession` shared instance, I setup the file with `NSURL`, `alloc` and `init` *recorder object of `AVAudioRecorder`, prepare to record. then `[recorder record]` or `[recorder recordforduration(NSTimer]` - i've tried both.

When I instantiate `*MyRecorder` as an object of class `ARecorder` from say... the `viewcontroller` and call `[... setupAndRecord]` method - the object is apparently created and released before the `AVAudioRecorder` object inside the `MYRecorder` instantiation has a chance to do anything... it creates the file, begins to record, and by then the object `MYRecorder` is apparently immediately released.

If i set a loop, or use @selector `afterdelay` in `*MYRecorder`, it will record...this is a hack and not the proper way.

I've set `*recorder` as property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioRecorder *recorder
```

I've declared it as an instance var as well. Nothing makes it stay allocated. I understand I need to use a property instead of allocate and init the AVAudioRecorder *recorder object inside a method? So how do I turn this

```
"recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL error:&err];"
```

into a property instead of a local instance?

If I move all this code to the viewcontroller - obviously the viewcontroller is retained in memory, so a `-void(setupAndRecord)` method that instantiates an `AVAudioRecorder` object will stay retained until finished - but isn't the point of the MVC pattern to separate model from view?

I also want to use the `audioRecorderdidfinishrecording delegate` in a viewcontroller - but I can't figure out how to get the instance of `AVAudioRecorder *recorder` in a `MYRecorder` object to use the `delegate` in ViewController.

I want the viewcontroller to be the `delegate` of `*recorder` and do something when `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording` is called at the end of `[recorder recordforduration...]`

Obviously the delegate method will not be called if the object is not staying in memory long enough to even record. But lets say `MYRecorder` object was being retained for some crazy reason, at the end of `[... recordforduration]`, how can it use the delegate method that is in the viewcontroller and not in MYRecorder? All I want the `MYRecorder` object to do is record and tell the `didfinishrecording` delegate in the viewcontroller when its done. Doesn't seem like it should be that difficult.

Comment: Oh dear god. Please spend some time formatting your question.

Comment: Thank you... new to SO - It really boils down to this:
`recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL error:&err];` is creating and releasing the instance immeidately. 

How do i store that instance in a property instead of in a local instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is ownership of your MyRecorder object.

I suggest you make MyRecorder a singleton. Do a search here on SO for the singleton design pattern in Objective-C. You should find plenty of examples.

Your strong property syntax is correct. If your MyRecorder has a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioRecorder *recorder
```

Then in your setup code in MyRecorder, you'd use code like this:

```
self.recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL error:&err];
```

Note that it reads self.recorder, not `recorder`. That uses the property's setter rather than accessing the instance variable directly, which you should get in the habit of doing.

Comment: Would something like the answer to this question suffice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164873? It appears he has created a singleton then uses it with: [[NIKPlayer sharedPlayer] playURL:audioURL]; [[NIKPlayer sharedPlayer].currentPlayer prepareToPlay];

Comment: Thank you...I created the singleton and it is working fine - now on to the delegation portion. I want my `viewcontroller` to be the delegate. I implement the `-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)sharedRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag` method of the delegate protocol in my VC, but the "recording" functionality is all happening in  the "recorder". How do i use the delegate in VC to find out when the "recorder" `didfinishrecording`?

Comment: If this solution worked, please mark it as accepted. You should probably create a new question for the delegation issue so it's easier for other SO users to find.